# MobileFirst 7.0 Application Center user management

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I have uploaded two apps on Application Center Console. I also have created two users that should see only one of the apps. I have teste with and without restrictions, but the users in appcenterusergroup cannot see any of the Apps. Server.xml configuration looks like this:

```
 <basicRegistry>
            <user name="demo" password="demo"/>
            <user name="salesappdemo" password="salesappdemo"/>
            <user name="admin" password="admin"/>     

        <group name="appcentergroup">     
            <member name="admin"/>
        </group>

         <group name="appcenterusergroup">
            <member name="demo"/>
            <member name="salesappdemo"/>
         </group>

    </basicRegistry>

    <application id="appcenterconsole" name="appcenterconsole" location="appcenterconsole.war" type="war">
        <application-bnd>
            <security-role name="appcenteradmin">
                <group name="appcentergroup"/>
            </security-role>
             <security-role name="appcenteruser">
             <group name="appcenterusergroup"/>
         </security-role>
        </application-bnd>
    </application>
```

To summarize:

-Installer check box in the AppcenterConsole is checked.

-The applications Access control is now Unrestricted. Later I plan to add restriction so that each user should see a different application.

-I added a appcenteruser Group into server.xml with two users that are not able to see the uploaded applications

-The admin user from appcenteradmin Group IS ABLE TO see and download the applications.

Am I missing something into server.xml or other LDAP configuration or is Application Center not working properly?

Comment: you are able to see in the app console but you are not able to see in the installer am i right

Comment: The problem is that the users I have created into the appcenterusergroup are not able to see the applications. Only the admin from appcentergroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I got it working, the error was that I added the group name into

```
<!-- Declare the IBM Application Center Console application. -->
<application id="appcenterconsole" name="appcenterconsole" location="appcenterconsole.war" type="war">
```

but correctly is to add here:

```
<!-- Declare the IBM Application Center Services application. -->
    <application id="applicationcenter" name="applicationcenter" location="applicationcenter.war" type="war">
```

**So user groups for mobilefirst-appcenter should be added into**

```
<application id="applicationcenter" name="applicationcenter" location="applicationcenter.war" type="war">**
```

To continue, when you want different users to get different applications, it does't work on web interface. you must install IBM App Center application on device. The apk is delivered with the Server. Only then the restrictions will work. Anyway distributing IBM App Center over Application Center drives to a security problem, while you must login on web, and the web allows seeing all applications, it cannot restrict user rights.

Comment: Could yo please tell me from where we can get applcationcenter.war file . I amn not able to find. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Uploading apk or ipa alone in the AppcenterConsole `/appcenterconsole/console.html` won't provide you with the installation in the `/applicationcenter/installers.html` installer.

> You need to check the installer check box in the AppcenterConsole
>   to view it on the installer

[image]

> The above Properties will appear once you click on the .apk or .ipa file in the `/appcenterconsole/console.html` just check the installer and click apply and ok buttons.

go to the `/appcenterconsole/console.html`

See the option called `AccessControl :` which will be present along with your apk file at the right side of you apk file like below image

[image]

> Click on that and there will be an option called  `Access control
>   enabled` check the box and `add your users or groups` or make it
>   unchecked so it is `unrestricted` so that all can use it.

Comment: I have done that already. When I log with the admin user on /appcenterconsole/console.html I can see the installer.

Comment: @OlimpiuOlar have you checked the installer to be applied for your apk

Comment: Yes, off course. It is valid. I have already installed the app when logging in with admin account. The problem that I am having is that I cannot enable the users from appcenterusergroup (demo and salesappdemo) to see the applications.

Comment: @OlimpiuOlar now see the answer.

Comment: the installer option is applied. The Apps have I also unrestricted access enabled, althow later I need to apply the restriction for each user.

Comment: @OlimpiuOlar check on the access control enabled and check weather the groups and users you are having are shown in the list.

Comment: I have disabled now access control. It states unrestricted. But the applications are not visible yet. Is there another LDAP group configuration that must be added to the Websphere? Should the server.xml groups i.e. appcentergroup and appcenterusergroup  be visible into Application Center Console?

Comment: yes you shoul be able to see your Groups in the `appcenterconsole/console.html#Main,UsersGroupsMain,GroupsList`

Comment: I am not seeing the Group names appcenterusergroup and appcentergroup configurated added into server.xml when I call appcenterconsole/console.html#Main,UsersGroupsMain,GroupsList . 
 
Is there a connection between the server.xml <group name="appcenterusergroup"> and the Groups that are created with User and Groups Management => Create Group ?

Comment: Could yo please tell me from where we can get applcationcenter.war file . I amn not able to find. Thanks